# Locale on polybar is in US format instead of BR

Tags: arch-linux, date, i3, locale

## Context:

I'm running ArcoLinux with i3 as my window manager and polybar as my bar.
During installation I chose the language to be English, America `en_us`.

And Locale I chose Brazil, São Paulo.

If I run on terminal `locale` I get the output as shown bellow:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

And if I run the command `date` I get:

```
sex 04 set 2020 10:31:27 -03
```

My polybar config for the date module is:

```
[module/date]
;https://github.com/jaagr/polybar/wiki/Module:-date
type = internal/date
; Seconds to sleep between updates
interval = 5
; See "http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time" for details on how to format the date string
; NOTE: if you want to use syntax tags here you need to use %%{...}
date = "%a %d/%m  %t"
;date-alt = "%x"
time = %H:%M
;time-alt = %H:%M
format-prefix = " "
format-prefix-foreground = ${colors.foreground}
;format-underline = #c1941a
;format-underline =${colors.foreground}
format-foreground = ${colors.foreground}
format-background = ${colors.background}
label = %date% %time%
```

And yet my output on my bar is
[image: polybar date module]

### How can I get date format in polybar to actually be as in the `date` command? It should be like it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the locale for the entire bar, by setting the `locale` key in the [bar section](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/Configuration#bar-settings). In your case that would be `locale = pt_BR.UTF-8`.

I am not aware of a way to set the locale just for the date module.

> How can I get date format in polybar to actually be as in the date command? It should be like it, right?

The date module is not the same as the `date` command. Internally polybar used C++'s [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time), which has some differences compared to the `date` command.

Comment: Thank you. This actually solved. I thought it would default to system locale's and the default configuration didn't come with the locale option.